# I'm trying to create an array with a certain number of elements, but when use a variable it doesnt work

Tags: java, arrays, string

Here I put a 4 value in the variable length. I'm supposed to get an array with 4 elements, but I can only input 3 elements.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int length;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Length: ");
    length = input.nextInt();
    String[] my_friend_names = new String[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        my_friend_names[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + my_friend_names[i]);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

- Length: 4
- 1
- 2
- 3
- Name:
- Name: 1
- Name: 2
- Name: 3

---

Now if I change the length variable for a number 4, it works!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] my_friend_names = new String[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        my_friend_names[i] = input.nextLine();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + my_friend_names[i]);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- Name: 1
- Name: 2
- Name: 3
- Name: 4

Do you know why that is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't use Scanner.nextInt() and Scanner.nextLine() together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036062/cant-use-scanner-nextint-and-scanner-nextline-together)

Answer (score 2):

This is because of incorrect use of the scanner api.
In the first example, when you used `input.nextInt();` it only read the integer part of that line, the new line char is still not used by the scanner.
Later when you call scanner.nextLine() it returns the chars after 4 which was your input and the new line which is an empty string.

This question has been answered before

[Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

[Can't use Scanner.nextInt() and Scanner.nextLine() together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036062/cant-use-scanner-nextint-and-scanner-nextline-together)

Comment: mmm when I called the scanner.nextLine() I input a 4 value in the variable "length" (so I'm declaring 4 elements in the array), then after that, I'm supposed to input 4 elements in the array but I'm only able to input 3 elements in the array, not 4. And when I print it gives me 4 arrays but one empty. still not sure why this is happening and how can I make it work with the variable "length" and still have the same results as my second example. Thank you for your answer

Comment: ok I understand now. When i press enter the scanner.nextLine() reads my enter input and that's why it was skipping one of my array inputs. So now I have to add an extra scanner.nextLine() just for the enter input.

this is what i wrote now and it works:
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Length: ");
        length = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine(); <--------- Im just adding this to my code for the enter input

Answer (score -1):

Java arrays are fixed. Try using a List instead.